# When I knit a flextable to html there is no output with the table

Tags: r, r-markdown, flextable

The table prints nicely in markdown but is not present in the knitted html file. I noticed that it is classified as a list but don't know how to change it to an acceptable file type. The knitted output is not formatted as a table. I appreciate the help.

```
library("crosstable") #important package crosstable() function
library('dplyr')
library("flextable")

tbl1 =  crosstable(mtcars2, c(1), by = 2) %>%
  as_flextable(keep_id=FALSE)
  print(tbl1)
```

Comment: If your concern is with why something is not printed in an rmarkdown document, it would be helpful (likely *necessary*) to show enough of the markdown document so that we can glean the global and chunk options.

Comment: Just remove the `print` i.e. use only `tbl1`

Answer (score 1):

According to `?print.flextable`

> Note also that a print method is used when flextable are used within **R markdown** documents. See **knit_print.flextable()**.

Therefore, if we want to print in Rmarkdown, either use `knitr::knit_print` or remove the `print` as the `?knit_print.flextable` documentation shows

> You should not call this method directly. **This function is used by the knitr package to automatically display a flextable in an "R Markdown" document from a chunk**.

````
---
title: "Testing"
author: "akrun"
date: "09/12/2021"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r, echo = FALSE}
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library("crosstable")) #important package crosstable() function
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library('dplyr'))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library("flextable"))

tbl1 =  crosstable(mtcars2, c(1), by = 2) %>%
    as_flextable(keep_id=FALSE)
 # either use knit_print or remove the print wrapper
 #knitr::knit_print(tbl1)
  tbl1   
```
````

-output

[image]